# Advice page on Ask Question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

The Advice page is displayed when Ask Question is clicked by a new user. However, this is not the same across all Stack Exchange sites. [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask/advice?) displays it but SuperUser does not auto redirect the user on Advice page. Can someone please guide me where can I find an official reference on this. Tried searching for it but no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is always the same; so you'll find it on Super User in the [exact same place](https://superuser.com/questions/ask/advice).

Use `http://$sitename/questions/ask/advice` to find it on any given site.

Wether or not a site actually *uses* this page is a matter of local configuration; each site's moderator team can decide on this locally. As such there is no central list of what sites do and what sites don't use it. If you have a low-reputation test account you could just try it yourself to see if a site does or not.