# Checkboxes for questions from new users

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users

There is the FAQ, but I don't think many new users visit it. As a result, we again and again see the same comments, which ask to show attempts, post compilable code, etc.

**Suggestion.** For users who ask questions for the **first** time, add checkboxes above "Post your question" button, like the following:

- I searched for the question using Google and Stack Overflow and didn't find an answer.
- I clearly specified the problem, included a complete error message, etc.
- I showed my attempt to solve the problem.
- My code is properly formatted, compiles, reproduces the error and is a minimal possible one.
- etc.

And users can't submit the question until they set all these checkboxes. For each checkbox the corresponding link (like [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) may be given.

Advantages:

- New user will be aware about Stack Overflow standards. Fewer bad questions => people don't waste their time.
- Users can get answers faster, since they don't waste time in question fixing cycle: others suggest a fix, OP fix, others suggest a fix, etc.
- Users can downvote without explaining the reason (which is useful since "What have you tried" and similar are banned, and I don't want to waste my time saying the same thing in a longer way).

Downsides: A bit more time before posting for the first time, if the question is already good.

Also the similar idea can be applied for users who answer for the first time, although it's less critical.

Comment: wat? "What have you tried" is banned?

Comment: Or "What did you try". Yes, at least for me.

Comment: Just to check, are you aware of [the question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378057) that is currently being tested on SO?

Comment: @Jenayah, I wasn't. But either I miss something (I don't see a complete description), or I don't see anything similar to what I suggest. By using checkboxes I want to force users to read this text.

Comment: Not that it's similar (wizard is more about the question's content, not SE's philosophy), just that I thought it might be put with it, as both would appear for first-time posters. Although truth be told... I guess a good chunk of "problem users" (read: help vampires) would just check everything and click "Post". :/

Comment: @Jenayah, agreed and agreed. But I think that we can have more confidence that OP is help vampire (compared to just not knowing what they should include in the question). Hopefully, Such questions will be closed faster, and they won't receive an answer.

Comment: New Stack Overflow (and Server Fault) users are *already* given instructions and are forced to check a checkbox before posting a question (this is different from the wizard since even I remember seeing it when I first asked on SO). I'd [like to see it customizable for each site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316489/323179) though.

Comment: @Laurel, I just tested it (from new account), and I don't see anything similar. About checkbox: are you talking about "What kind of question do you ask?"? It's not enough. Just giving instructions is also not enough.

Comment: @dyukha I mean [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?) (it's almost the same between sites). You might not see it on Stack Overflow if you get the wizard though. Server Fault is the site to test on since you can just use an incognito window without needing another account.